# I'm seeing "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment" on spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, differential-equations, runge-kutta

What exactly does this mean? Should I not use a for loop? Do I need another tuple?

For context: I'm trying to use Huen's method to solve dydt=y/((t+1)**2) with step size h=0.2 at t=0,0.2,0.4,0.6

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def dydt(t,y):
    dfdt = y / ((t + 1) ** 2)
    return dfdt

def IVPsolver2(dydt_fun, y0, t0, t1, t2, tf, h):
    n = 50 #points
    h = (tf-t0)/(n-1) #step size
    t = np.linspace(t0,t1,t2,tf,n)
    y = np.zeros(n) #preallocate zeros
    yp = np.zeros(n)
    m = np.zeros(n)
    mc = np.zeros(n)
    yp[0] = y0 #first yp at y0
    y[0] = y0 #y is 0
    t[0] = 0 #t is 0
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        m[i] = dydt_fun(t[i-1],y[i-1]) #calculating slope
        yp[i] = y[i] + m[i]*h #calculating predicted y at slope y
        mc[i] = dydt_fun(t[i+1],yp[i]) #slope corrector, 2 step
        t[i+1] = t[i] + h #t going by stepsize
        y[i+1] = y[i] + ((m[i]+mc[i])/2)*h #corrected y
    return t, y

def main(): #plotting  
    x2, y2 = IVPsolver2(dydt, 1, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2)
    plt.plot(x2,y2, 'o', mfc = 'purple')

    return
main()
```

Comment: Where is the error occurring? Also, you might be able to reduce the size of that loop through vectorization, but I can’t tell for sure.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this line: `t = np.linspace(t0,t1,t2,tf,n)` ?

Comment: The error is occuring in line 33.

Comment: As for the t = np.linspace(t0,t1,t2,tf,n) I'm trying to return evenly spaced numbers over the specified interval but maybe I'm misunderstanding how to properly implement it.

Comment: Your loop and indexing is very suspect. For `i = 0`, you're computing everything on the last element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your `np.linspace` statement. Here is doc for [`linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). The syntax is: `numpy.linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False, dtype=None, axis=0)`. So you only need to give the starting and ending points, and the number of intervals you would like. So after changing your program to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def dydt(t,y):
    dfdt = y / ((t + 1) ** 2)
    return dfdt

def IVPsolver2(dydt_fun, y0, t0, t1, t2, tf, h):
    n = 50 #points
    h = (tf-t0)/(n-1) #step size
    t = np.linspace(t0,tf,n) # <----- see change here ---- 
    y = np.zeros(n) #preallocate zeros
    yp = np.zeros(n)
    m = np.zeros(n)
    mc = np.zeros(n)
    yp[0] = y0 #first yp at y0
    y[0] = y0 #y is 0
    t[0] = 0 #t is 0
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        m[i] = dydt_fun(t[i-1],y[i-1]) #calculating slope
        yp[i] = y[i] + m[i]*h #calculating predicted y at slope y
        mc[i] = dydt_fun(t[i+1],yp[i]) #slope corrector, 2 step
        t[i+1] = t[i] + h #t going by stepsize
        y[i+1] = y[i] + ((m[i]+mc[i])/2)*h #corrected y
    return t, y

def main(): #plotting  
    x2, y2 = IVPsolver2(dydt, 1, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2)
    plt.plot(x2,y2, 'o', mfc = 'purple')
    plt.show()
    return
main()
```

Your program gives this:

[image]

You can play with linspace as you like, to fit your criteria.

Comment: Thank you! That looks great, hopefully that is correct for Huen's method

Comment: @sayandip, you just beat me to answer :) .. I guess I wont be posting it then.

Comment: This solves the direct problem of the question, but still contains errors relative to the task. Which is the on-topic answer on SO, everything else is (theoretically) more on-topic on scicomp.SE or math.SE. This should perhaps be mentioned as caution on work yet-to-be-done. // In the plot interface you could use the disk icon to save the image to png, or use directly `plt.savefig("numgraph.png"), so that the image here only contains the plot, not also the window menu and decorations.

Answer (score 2):

The trapezoidal method of Karl Heun (published 1900) is a one-step method. This means that in the computation of `y[i+1]` you only use the data `y[i]` at time `t[i]`, there should be no `y[i-1]` in the loop.

Further there is no need to have `yp, m, mp` as arrays, as only the step-local value is used in the step, and nowhere else.

For the interface, it would make sense to accept an arbitrary time array, as one-step methods are uniquely suited to have variable step sizes (even if the array passed has constant step size as a special case). This would then also allow to remove the time array from the return values, in a manner similar to `odeint`.

```
def IVPsolver2(dydt_fun, y0, t):
    y = np.zeros(len(t)) #preallocate zeros
    y[0] = y0 #y is 0
    for i in range(0,len(t)-1):
        h = t[i+1] - t[i];
        m = dydt_fun(t[i],y[i]) #calculating slope
        yp = y[i] + m*h #calculating predicted y at slope y
        mc = dydt_fun(t[i+1],yp) #slope corrector, 2 step
        y[i+1] = y[i] + ((m+mc)/2)*h #corrected y
    return y
```

If you wanted to keep the time array construction inside the procedure, only pass `t0, tf, h` and use

```
t = np.arange(t0,tf+0.1*h, h);
```

The increased end value is needed to have a value close to `tf` in the array, due to rounding errors in the construction of the arithmentic sequence that is not always automatically the case, even if `tf` is an element of the exact arithmetic sequence.

Finally you can apply this method twice to the given sequence of sample times and a denser sequence to provide a more exact solution

```
x1 = np.linspace(0,1,5+1);
y1 = IVPsolver2(dydt, 1, x1);
x2 = np.linspace(0,1,5*10+1);
y2 = IVPsolver2(dydt, 1, x2);
xe = np.linspace(t0,tf,152);
ye = np.exp(1-1/(1+xe));
plt.plot(xe,ye,c='lightgray', lw=6)
plt.plot(x2,y2, 'o', mfc = 'purple', ms=2)
plt.plot(x1,y1, '-o', mfc = 'red', ms=4)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of the numerical solutions]